# What are the average per-passenger-kilogram carbon emissions of common commercial passenger aircraft per kilometer?

Tags: efficiency, carbon-footprint

Or said in another way, does packing lighter on a trip actually make a dent in one's co2 emissions?

According to [The carbon independent site](https://www.carbonindependent.org/22.html),

> CO2 emissions from aviation fuel are 3.15 grams per gram of fuel [38] , which gives CO2 emissions from a Boeing 737-400 of 115 g per passenger km.

What it does not talk about, however, is the weight of the passengers and their luggage.  Any write-ups on that?

What are the average per-passenger-kilogram carbon emissions of common commercial passenger aircraft per kilometer?

Comment: There are so many"it depends" variables that any answer here is almost meaningless. Full aircraft, or half full? Short hop, or long haul? Old aircraft (like the 737-400 mentioned), or more modern? Flying a "least fuel" (slow) profile, a min time (more fuel burn) profile, or something in between? VTC as unanswerably broad.

Comment: If you care enough about this to worry about nickel and dime numbers like that, why are you traveling at all?

Comment: You may restrict your question to a specific aircraft type (e.g. an embraer E-jet) and a specific route (to have a taxi, climbing, cruising and descent time)

Comment: @Therac yes thanks!  So about 1/20kg co2 per kg luggage  per flight hour for an A320!

Comment: @begs-the-hessian Approximately 40-50 grams fuel and correspondingly 130-150 grams CO2 per hour flight per kg payload. This will hold approximately across various aircraft types (the A320 takes a bit less fuel than average due to being short-range and modern).